# Xamarin.Android Linker issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-linker

I have an old Xamarin Androd project that used to work in release mode. Now after around 8-9 months there are some changes so i did them and checked the application which working fine in Debug mode. But when i try to run it release mode, the app crashes. Below is the error log from android monitor from when the crash happens.

```
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511): android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to construct LocalCacheService ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libsqlite3_xamarin assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroidNInternal.sqlite3_config(SQLite.Net.Interop.ConfigOption)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroidN.Config (SQLite.Net.Interop.ConfigOption option) [0x00000] in <360d65bfaa3e44c0b2b5840d827a452d>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at CygMobile.Droid.Helpers.SQLiteConnectionFactory.Create (System.String database) [0x00029] in <f456e9b7efc54b949a703cf133b30114>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at CygMobile.Core.Services.LocalCacheService..ctor (CygMobile.Core.Interfaces.ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory) [0x00012] in <19ac0b1a45404947b9cc363b69761b6e>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <b3da7d1603ac4e70afba2b0463d79a7b>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x0001d] in <b3da7d1603ac4e70afba2b0463d79a7b>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00086] in <b3da7d1603ac4e70afba2b0463d79a7b>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <b3da7d1603ac4e70afba2b0463d79a7b>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <b3da7d1603ac4e70afba2b0463d79a7b>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x0003a] in <cec644c19aec488eb4600e7788c2008f>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x0005b] in <cec644c19aec488eb4600e7788c2008f>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct[T] () [0x00005] in <cec644c19aec488eb4600e7788c2008f>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton[TInterface,TType] () [0x00005] in <cec644c19aec488eb4600e7788c2008f>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at CygMobile.Droid.MiniSetup.InitializeServices (Android.Content.Context applicationContext) [0x0000f] in <f456e9b7efc54b949a703cf133b30114>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at CygMobile.Droid.MiniSetup.EnsureInit (Android.Content.Context applicationContext) [0x00057] in <f456e9b7efc54b949a703cf133b30114>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at CygMobile.Droid.SplashActivity.Startup () [0x00000] in <f456e9b7efc54b949a703cf133b30114>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at CygMobile.Droid.SplashActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00017] in <f456e9b7efc54b949a703cf133b30114>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <d0ba74ae6dd346ba93d5085dca229dd8>:0 
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.3(intptr,intptr,intptr)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at md508c3e82ce365ea781ae67f1d3460864c.SplashActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at md508c3e82ce365ea781ae67f1d3460864c.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:31)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
10-22 15:51:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(16511):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

After some research i found that there is some issue with linker. The current selection is Link SDKs assembly only. Which crashes the app.
If i select Link None then the application works fine.

I have already tried things from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker.Those didn't work.

Still If anyone can help on this, that will be help full.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the bin obj folders and updating to the latest NuGet packages?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but proguard may be deleting some necessary symbols within the SQLite libraries. Was the SQLite dependency added recently?

Comment: No. And also there is no option selected under code shrinker as well. So i thing Proguard is not being used.

Comment: There is an option called "Enable ProGuard" under your project's properties -> Android Options. This is on VS 2017 (the windows version). Is it checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved By adding Mono.Data.Sqlite to Skip Linikingassemblies.
Thanks to @Saranga Athukorale for helping to head in that direction.

Apparently when you build your app using neww Visualstudio, it is having issue while accessing that dll.

Comment: glad to hear that you have solved your issue, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like proguard is removing some SQLite related symbols. You can make proguard skip these libraries by visiting ***your project's properties*** -> ***Android Options*** -> ***Skip linking assemblies*** -> set value to

```
SQLite-net;SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green;SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2;SQLitePCLRaw.core;SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3
```

Comment: According to this thread (https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/42/42507/bug.html#c17), you have to reference Mono.Data.Sqlite.

Comment: I have already referenced it, that is why it was working previously.

Comment: This worked!, but by question is there any other better solution than this?